# javascript unique key values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, unique, associative

I need to find out, is there in array of objects object with the certain key:value
For example if I need the key 'id' to be unique:

```
arr=[
     {id:1,  attr1:'435',attr2:'sdg'},
     {id:2,  attr3:'4x35',attr2:'sdg'}
    ];

a={id:1,attr2:'nnsklnf'};
b={id:3,attr3:'kldfmlkdblng'};

function isHaveSimilar(_a,_array){
 // ... ???
}

isHaveSimilar(a,arr); // true
isHaveSimilar(b,arr); // false
```

Maybe there is some easier way than the rude checking of the each element? Thx)

Comment: No, I believe the "rude check" is the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function hasSimilar(needle, haystack) {
  for (item in haystack) {
    if (haystack[item].id == needle.id) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

hasSimilar(a, arr); // true
hasSimilar(b, arr); // false
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't see another way also. Thought maybe there is something that allowed to solve it in one line in jQuery or maybe some function in JSON, it maybe useless but just curious :]